# how ram and rom size is depend on cpu?

Tags: memory, embedded, cpu, microcontroller, 8051

I am very interested to know how CPU is working. let say in 8-bit microcontroller(8051) how ram and rom in depends on cpu? according to these topics, I have some question in my mind which is confusing me. like 
          1 = how to ram and rom size is defined(in 8051 microcontroller)?
          2 = what means of 8-bit controller?
          3 = is rom size is depend on CPU size? if not so how much rom I interface with 8-bit controller?

I searched more regarding to this my questions but not found any solutions so please help me

and is there any have some document and books(microcontroller) so please suggest me

Thanks,

Comment: Too broad - if the question is specifically about 8051, make that clear, because 8051 is architecturally quirky and any answer to that may not relate to other architecture devices. Also you have conflated a number of concepts and posed a number of questions - better to keep question simple, to the point and singular.  Apart from that the "8-bit" description refers to the data width, the addressable space depends on the address bus width and on 8051 the _Harvard Architecture_ - but even then it is not that simple - bank switching may be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below answers for your questions as per my knowledge.

1) The 8051 microcontroller's memory is divided into Program Memory and Data Memory. Program Memory (ROM) is used for permanent saving program being executed, while Data Memory (RAM) is used for temporarily storing and keeping intermediate results and variables.

2) an 8-bit microcontroller processes 8-bits of data at any particular time. The number of bits used by an MCU (sometimes called bit depth or data width) tells you the size of the registers (8 bits per register), number of memory addresses (only 2^8 = 256 addresses), and the largest numbers they can process (again, 2^8 = 256 integers, or integers 0 through 255). An 8-bit microcontroller has limited addressing, but some 8-bit microcontrollers use paging, where the contents of a page register determines which onboard memory bank to use.

3) Yes, The maximum rom size can be addressed by CPU depending of the width of address bus. for example in 8085 microprocessor the width of the address bus is 16bit so it can address upto 2^16 = 65536 (8 Bit values).

Comment: Thanks for your replay, have you any documents or any book suggestions for deeply understanding

Comment: Please refer below book for you understanding. "The 8051 Microcontroller and Embedded Systems Using Assemble and C". author name : Mazidi

Answer (score 2):

Not much different than the above answer...

In all of this there are no definitive definitions, they are often a slang or engineer speak or marketing speak for things.  8-bit is a little bit more firm, with exceptions.  It implies that the processor operations or maximum size of the bulk of the operations is 8 bits wide, so an 8 bit wide alu if you will.  Some folks try to make the register size define the bit size, the instruction size, some the number of address bits on the cpu core, etc.  So is an x86 an 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit, 64-bit, 128, 256, 512 or 1024 based on above notions?  could be any depending on who you ask...

The 8051 is considered 8-bit based on the time frame and that most things in it are 8 bit in size.

The 8051 has been so heavily cloned and as mentioned banking is sometimes used to expand the memory space, so it depends on the specific cpu/part/core you are using as to how much total it can access.  ROM/RAM sizes are also specific to the part you are using, you start with the datasheet from the part vendor and then as needed other documentation.  The part/IP vendor is the definitive source for RAM/ROM information for the 8051 variant you are using at any particular time.

Microcontrollers in general not just 8051s will tend to have more ROM/FLASH than RAM, it should be obvious why when you start writing applications and see that you need more of one than the other.

As answered by Guna the maximum addressing space is determined by the number of address bits on "the bus", but as mentioned above that can/will vary by implementation, there are some that can address a megabyte some that can only address some number of K bytes.

Some CPU architectures are more controlled than others, either by documentation and versions or by ownership and control of the IP (no clones that survive lawsuits for example).  So some will have a fixed address space size and currently have no exceptions, but then there are those like the 8051 that have been cloned so heavily (8051s are still widely in use, there is a good chance your computer has at least one, if not the servers along the internet and websites like this definitely will) both their original clocking scheme and address space options vary from implementation to implementation.  So this is not a case of the CPU name/type/brand determines maximum amount of ram/rom, and it almost never will determine the exact amount of each you have in a specific implementation, a specific chip or board.

It is very easy to find 8051 information, countless websites, more than there is space to provide links.  Start with some chip vendors still actively producing 8051 chips.  Silicon labs, microchip, cypress, and perhaps others.

For example it took only a few seconds to find a datasheet for a specific part that states:

512 bytes RAM

8 kB (F990/1/6/7, F980/1/6/7), 4 kB (F982/3/8/9), or 2 kB (F985) Flash; in-system programmable

The price of the part is heavily influenced by the ROM/FLASH size and the RAM size, so a particular family of parts will essentially have the same design with different sized memories depending on your needs, if you can keep the program smaller you can buy a part that is say a dollar less than another in the family but may have the same footprint so that design for the larger one and switch to the smaller one or vice versa hope for the smaller one and if your program is too big then have to switch to the bigger one and deal with the profit loss.

Comment: Historical note: Memory banking was a common technique on original Intel 8051/31 designs even before it was directly supported by derivative devices, using a GPIO port to drive the bank select logic.  The derivatives with banking have more-or-less simply integrated that logic on the die.

Comment: good to know, was trying to imply banking in some form to be a common solution for any cpu design with a small address space including the 8051.  By the time I had one dallas semi was the leading provider and intel was out of the picture.